# 条件によっては行を返さないサブクエリをCROSS JOINしたい

Tags: sql

[テーブル：Person]
name
－－－
Sato
Suzuki
Takahashi

みたいなテーブルがあったとして、ここから異なる条件にマッチするフィールドを横に並べて表示するために、CROSS JOINするとします。

SELECT A.name B.name
FROM ( SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name = 'Sato' ) A,
     ( SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name = 'Takahashi' ) B;

[結果]
name | name
Sato | Takahashi

このときサブクエリで行が返ってくればいいのですが、WHERE句で引っかからない場合はCROSS JOINで何も返ってこなくなります。

SELECT A.name B.name
FROM ( SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name = 'Hoge' ) A,
     ( SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name = 'Takahashi' ) B;

[結果]
name | name

こちらが望む結果としては↑のような場合に
[結果]
name | name
null | Takahashi
となって欲しいのですが、なにかいい方法ありませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

完全外部結合やSELECT句の副問い合わせで実現できますが…。
ロジックを見直して、別々のSQLで取得するのが「いい方法」のように思います。

Oracleでの完全外部結合の例:

```
with Person as
(select 'Suzuki' name from dual union all
 select 'Sato' name from dual union all
 select 'Takahashi' name from dual)

SELECT A.name, B.name
FROM ( SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name = 'Hoge' ) A FULL OUTER JOIN
( SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name = 'Takahashi' ) B ON 1 = 1
```

OracleでのSELECT句の副問い合わせの例:

```
with Person as
(select 'Suzuki' name from dual union all
 select 'Sato' name from dual union all
 select 'Takahashi' name from dual)

SELECT (SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name = 'Hoge'),
       (SELECT name FROM Person WHERE name = 'Takahashi')
FROM   dual
```